# disabling the default context menu(design time) of a control in winform designer

Tags: c#, winforms

I have created a control which is derived from `TableLayoutPanel`. When I drag and drop that control in WinForms designer, on right click it displays the default context menu of `TableLayoutPanel`.

I need to disable this default context menu of this control during design time. I tried overriding `ContextMenu` and `ContextMenuStrip` but it doesn't help.

**Approach 1: overriding ContextMenu**

```
public class MyControl : TableLayoutPanel
{
    public MyControl()
    {
    }
    public override ContextMenu ContextMenu { get => new ContextMenu();}
    public override ContextMenuStrip ContextMenuStrip { get => new ContextMenuStrip(); }
}
```

**Approach 2: sending ESC key when user right click on the MyControl so that context menu doesn't appear**

```
public class MyDesignerForm
{
     ISelectionService service = (ISelectionService)serviceContainer.GetService(typeof(ISelectionService));
     Application.AddMessageFilter(new MyControl(),service);
}
internal class MyMsgFilter : IMessageFilter
       {
            const int WM_RBUTTONDOWN = 0x0204;
            const int WM_KEYDOWN = 0x100;
            const int WM_KEYUP = 0x101;
            const int VK_ESCAPE = 0x1B;
            Control m_control;
            [DllImport("User32.dll")]
            public static extern bool PostMessage(IntPtr hwnd, int uMsg, int wParam, int lParam);
            ISelectionService service = null;
            public MyMsgFilter(Control control,ISelectionService Service)
            {
                this.m_control = control;
                service = Service;
            }
            private void SendEscape(IntPtr hwnd)
            {
                PostMessage(hwnd, WM_KEYDOWN, VK_ESCAPE, 0);
                PostMessage(hwnd, WM_KEYUP, VK_ESCAPE, 0);
            }

            #region IMessageFilter Members
            public bool PreFilterMessage(ref Message m)
            {
                long wParam, lParam;
                bool result;

                if(m.Msg==WM_RBUTTONDOWN)
                {
                    SendEscape(m_control.Handle);
                    return true;
                }
                return false;
            }
            #endregion
        }
```

Comment: Could you be more specific? Show us what you've tried so far

Comment: You have to replace the [Designer].  This is not practical, don't ask an XY question please.

Comment: I have added the code which I tried.

Comment: yes, I have a custom designer which is implementing IDesignerHost, IComponentChangeService etc...